# Read and write dictionary values c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need help. These are the instructions:

Please add a new value, the key of which is your name, and the value of which is your age. Do this using the Add method.

Next, add another value to the dictionary using the index notation. This time, use a different name and a different age.

Lastly, read the first item you added to the dictionary, and write it to the console using Console.WriteLine.

The last step is the one that I am missing. I cannot figure out how to print the first element in my collection. I get "cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> people = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        people.Add("John Doe", 23);
        people["John Foe"] = 27;  
        
        Console.WriteLine(people[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `System.Linq`?

Comment: Probably you should read the first key you add: `Console.WriteLine(people["John Doe"]);`

Comment: You might want to use `people["John Doe"]` since the key of your `Dictionary` is of type `string`, not `int`.

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0HZIT0 It will look clunky, because Dictionary is not meant to be accessed by index, but by key. If the instruction means to use the key, then use that instead.

Comment: The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  That means you can `foreach` over the collection, getting a `KeyValuePair` in each iteration (`foreach(var kvp in people) { }`).   That will get you every item in the dictionary.  The key will be available as `kvp.Key` and the value as `kvp.Value`. Because this is a very small collection, they will be in insertion order.  Just get the first one and break out of the loop

Comment: @Flydog57 Voted to reopen. Closing also caused me to comment a fiddle instead of answering (had it in the editor and then I couldn't post, grrr) :) Coincidently I implmented your approach there.

Answer (score 3):

Please note, that `Dictionary` doesn't have 1st or 2nd items, the *order is not guaranteed*.
Technically you can use *Linq* and put

```
using System.Linq;

...
// Get values and return the 1st item whatever it is
Console.WriteLine(people.Values.ElementAt(0));
```

but there's no guarantee that you'll get `23`. I think that you should read "first item you added to the dictionary" as "the key you have added at the very beginning"

```
// You've started the exercise with "John Doe" 
Console.WriteLine(people["John Doe"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you need the first item of the Dictionary. You can do it just like this

```
using System.Linq;

Console.WriteLine(people.First());

//or 

Console.WriteLine(people.ToArray()[1]); //the second element
```

if you need John Doe age

```
Console.WriteLine(people["John Doe"]); //23
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered i think the instructions ment call `get` passing in `"John Doe"`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is OP problem. He wants the first item of a dictionary.

Comment: @Fildor I am sorry, but I don't think that this question is worth of  a discussion

Comment: No worries. You already addressed it in your answer, meanwhile.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you as you are trying to get information that you have inserted in the dictionary at first.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> people = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            people.Add("John Doe", 23);
            people["John Foe"] = 27;

            //To get the first inserted pair in the dictionary
            Console.WriteLine(people.First());

            //To get the Key from the first inserted pair in the dictionary
            Console.WriteLine(people.ToList()[0].Key);

            //To get the Age from the first inserted pair in the dictionary
            Console.WriteLine(people.ToList()[0].Value);
        }
    }
}
```